# Akka persistence Cassandra, database initialisation

Tags: cassandra, akka-persistence

I am wondering what the most helpful pattern for initialising the akka-persistence database in Cassandra is.

At this time, I am using a custom Docker image with the database already created. However, I do not want to rely on docker and would like to use a standalone/non containerized instance.

The simplest pattern would be to connect to that database and execute the scripts manually before starting the application. But I would like to use a more automatic solution that will also work easily in local environments where the database can be deleted many times a day.

So I am wondering to use an initializing script/class that will connect to the database and execute the scripts. Sadly, I do not find any simple way to get the Cassandra connection from my (Playframework) application.

How do you initialize the database in your akka-persistence systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that automation of Cassandra schema generation is something that should not be done in production, at least not in a situation where that automation could be done from multiple machines.  This is because there's a very good chance that the keyspace(s, if also using Akka Persistence Cassandra as a snapshot store) will be simultaneously created on multiple nodes of the Cassandra cluster (even if using `IF NOT EXISTS` etc.) with different schema UUIDs.  Cassandra will eventually reconcile them and determine that the different schemas are actually the same, but in the meantime, there will be unpredictable data loss.

Akka Persistence Cassandra used to automatically create the keyspace/tables, but due to this issue, it no longer does.  However, if configured (e.g. via `application.conf` or a JVM property), it will create the keyspace/tables.  Just set `akka.persistence.cassandra.journal.keyspace-autocreate` and `akka.persistence.cassandra.snapshot.keyspace-autocreate` to `true`.  This sets up the schema for local dev use (e.g. a replication factor of 1).

You can set the journal's keyspace name with `akka.persistence.cassandra.journal.keyspace` and the replication factor to be used when auto-creating with `akka.persistence.cassandra.journal.replication-factor`.

If you can be sure that you're only creating the schema from a single instance of the application at a time and will use `nodetool describecluster` to determine that there's schema agreement before starting any other instances, you can enable auto-creation in production: be careful if doing this to set the `replication-factor` properly.

It's also possible to build a project just for creating the schema by depending on Akka Persistence Cassandra: the most straightforward approach is something like this:

```scala
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("cassandra-tables")

  import actorSystem.dispatcher

  // check Cassandra docs on how to create a CqlSession:
  val cqlSession = ???

  val cassandraPluginSettings = akka.persistence.cassandra.PluginSettings(actorSystem)

  val cassandraStatements = new akka.persistence.cassandra.CassandraStatements(cassandraPluginSettings)

  val schemaCreationFuture =
    cassandraStatements.executeAllCreateKeyspaceAndTables(cqlSession, akka.event.Logging(actorSystem, getClass))

  schemaCreationFuture.foreach(_ => actorSystem.terminate())

  Await.ready(system.whenTerminated, Duration.Inf)
}
```

Because this uses a couple of classes which are `private[akka]`, you'd need this `main` method to be in a package in the `akka` hierarchy, e.g. `akka.gervaisb`.  Doing this sort of thing is effectively opting in to having to deal with changes whenever you upgrade APC, though it probably behooves one to look for schema changes when upgrading APC anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. In the meantime, I have found that Liquibase support Cassandra. Because it has a lock mechanism, do you think it can solve the "multiple keyspace" that you described?

> Liquibase uses a DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK table to ensure that only one instance of Liquibase runs [..]. Even if you have a cluster of servers [..] 
> --https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/using-liquibase-java-api.html

https://docs.liquibase.com/install/tutorials/cassandra.html

Comment: Depending on the implementation details, it might be able to serve as the coordination layer to prevent simultaneous DDL execution.  I'd advise experimentation.

Comment: " I'd advise experimentation" for sure. I'll go for that but keep your proposal of creating a project to create the schemas. Thanks for your valuable answer.